# GitLab & GitLab CI WebHook Error

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm running GitLab 7.11.4 and GitLab CI 7.11.4, both installed via the Omnibus package. I've been running GitLab for awhile now, but have only just recently enabled the CI service. I have successfully setup GitLab and CI so that they're accessible at [code.subdomain.com] and [ci.subdomain.com] respectively. I've followed the instructions to enable CI access for one specific project, I've setup a runner, and I've made one test shell script for building (Basically: `cmake .. && make`).

This is where I hit problems. I'm supposed to visit my GitLab project settings page and hit "Test settings". When I do this, I receive the error `We tried to send a request to the provided URL but an error occured`. gitlab-rails/production.log shows this:

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started GET "/[namespace]/[project]/services/gitlab_ci/test" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-17 13:33:54 -0400
Processing by Projects::ServicesController#test as HTML
Parameters: {"namespace_id"=>"[namespace]", "project_id"=>"[project]", "id"=>"gitlab_ci"}
WebHook Error => getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

I've replaced [namespace] and [project] in that log, but they do show the correct entries.

GitLab CI never seems to receive the request and trying to do a test commit on my project also doesn't trigger GitLab CI.

I'm at a loss for what to do and can't seem to find any documentation on what might be causing this issue. Any help or direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem sort of solved. I had to add a loopback reference into /etc/hosts for ci.subdomain.com.

```
127.0.2.1       ci.subdomain.com    ci
```

This seems like maybe something I shouldn't have to do if my DNS has properly published my domain? Maybe someone can clarify why this was required.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why it was necessary to add the loopback reference in /etc/hosts? I was having the same problem and your fix did the trick for me too, but I wonder as well...

Comment: I believe what was happening was that I'm working in a university and my building network manager was running a DNS that was supposed to sync with the campus DNS, but never actually did. He had added my domain to his DNS, but the CI server was pulling from the campus DNS and not his. With the integration of CI into Gitlab CE, though, I believe this became a moot point.

Comment: I see. Perhaps I ran into something similar, then, as the company I work for has a couple of our own DNS's, and that it hadn't even been 24 hours yet since my `ci.subdomain.com` was registered? The integration you mention is with versions starting from 8.0, correct? Perhaps I should start looking at updating our GitLab version.